# How to resolve exception for javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable in GWT?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jetty, jax-rs

I am trying to build a simple rest application using JAX-RS in GWT. I have included all the necessary classes in class path. I am getting error in com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl - can someone please guide me on this? Thank you!

My Service is as below.

```
@Path("/hellos")
@Provider()
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        System.out.println("I am here");

        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }
}
```

My Web.xml is as below

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.test.rest.server</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>


SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that all of the technologies you plan to use are compatible with App Engine. If they are, see if any special configuration settings are necessary (see, for example, Jersey):

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

Comment: Thanks a ton! I found following web page from the url you gave it pointed me to correct version of jersey that was compatible with googleappengine. Thanks! http://iqbalyusuf.wordpress.com/googles-app-engine-java/google-app-engine-jax-rs-jersey/

Comment: You link is broken